# datasource causes sopui test to fail

Tags: mysql, jdbc, groovy, soapui, data-driven-tests

I have a test case in which I have a jdbc datasource step, for each data row returned I have to do some validation to check if the value in a specific column exists; if the value does not exist then I insert it for that column. Datasource returns around 1000 records. I am using stored procedures to insert missing values.

When I run the test-steps individually all of them pass, however :

- when running the whole testcase step(7) fails.
- If I disable step (1) and step (8) then the testcase passes.
- I also tried to disable step (1) using groovy script in (2) and re-enabling it after step(7) but no success.

I am using `ReadyAPI 2.2.0 pro`. I can't figure out what is going wrong. I have attached the pseudo test-structure here :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/afDI7.png

**List of Steps**

1. JDBC DataSource
2. check if  column 'x' has value- if yes go to (1) else go to (2) {groovy}
3. update 'a' prerequisite for 'b'
4. update 'b' prerequisite for 'x'
5. update 'x'
6. check if column 'y' has value {groovy}
7. insert value 'y' ('x' is prerequisite for y)
8. DataSource Loop

Comment: Please, read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to a bug in datasource step in Readyapi v 2.3